# add a value from one column to another after an update of a trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have on my table a column `col1` that goes decreasing. When `col1` gets to take the value 0 I want `col1` takes the value of a column called `col2` and col2 pass to take the value 0.

PD: I already have a trigger that decreases the column when I do insertions. When my trigger finally arrives to let `col1=0` I'd need other trigger that change `col1` by `col2`, and `col2=0`. I've tried with the following trigger, but doesn't work

```
create Trigger tr on table
after insert,update As
declare @id int
set @id=(select inserted.ID_TABLE from inserted)

UPDATE table
    SET col1 = CASE WHEN col1=0 THEN col2                 
    END
UPDATE table
set col2=0
where ID_TABKE=@id
```

Comment: This requirement is really weird. Anyway, you are already using one trigger, why don't you add this condition there?

Comment: Your code is extremely brittle and very likely to not do what you want because you are using scalar values in your trigger. What happens when inserted has more than 1 row? It can and will happen at some point regardless of the front end and your trigger needs to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Code
Update table name "`TableTrigger`" with your Table name

```
create Trigger tr on TableTrigger
after insert,update 
As

UPDATE TableTrigger
SET col1 =  CASE WHEN TableTrigger.col1=0 THEN TableTrigger.col2 else TableTrigger.col1 END,
    col2 =  CASE WHEN TableTrigger.col1=0 THEN 0 else TableTrigger.col2 END  
from TableTrigger
       JOIN inserted 
         ON TableTrigger.id = inserted.id
```

Comment: Thanks!!, I don't know why, but when `col1=0` appears `col1=col2-1` instead of `col1=col2`

Comment: "PD: I already have a trigger that decreases the column when I do insertions" @@User you need to check that trigger you mentioned in question. 2nd I agree with @Lamak if possible merge the logic in one trigger instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

Try this untested.Since you didn't mention that col1 should be updated only when col1=0 so i removed case

```
UPDATE A
SET    a.col1 = b.col2,
       a.col2 = 0
FROM   table a
       JOIN inserted b
         ON a.id = b.id
```